# Python: how to automatically create an instance in another class

Tags: python, class, python-2.5

In writing a Python (2.5) program, I tried to create a class and, in its `__init__` function, automatically create an instance of another class with its name as an argument to the `__init__` function, something like this:

```
    class Class1:
        def __init__(self,attribute):
            self.attribute1=attribute

    class Class2:
        def __init__(self,instanceName):
            #any of Class2's attributes
            exec instanceName + '=Class1('attribute1')'
            # this should produce an instance of Class1 whose name is instanceName
```

But when I make an instance of Class2, `instance=Class2('instance2')`, and try to get attribute1 of instance2 (which should have been created from Class2's `__init__` function) I get an error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
        print instance2.attribute1
    NameError: name 'instance2' is not defined
```

I don't know what the problem is, since `name='instance3'` and 
`exec name+'=Class1('attribute1')` does work, though this is probably because I don't have much experience with Python. How would I be able to do something like this automatically when an instance is created?

Comment: In Python 2, shouldn't your classes extend `object`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I'm pretty sure there's a way to do what you want that doesn't involve this structure.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem - why do you have the requirement to assign the instance to a specific name? And right now you're trying to create it as a local variable, which makes little sense as it's only accessible in the local scope. What's your use case?

Comment: This still does not work when I add `exec 'global '+instancename`, which should make it accessible as a global variable.

Comment: My purpose in this is to be able to create an instance of Class1 from one of Class2 while also being able to create an instance without using Class2, and this is the only way I know of to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure I get that correctly, but I don't see why that requires the _variable name_ to be dynamic. What would be the problem with assigning the instance to, say, `self.someInstance` instead of a dynamic name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to run, so hopefully, someone else can fix any mistakes in this post:

```
class Class1:
  def __init__(self, attribute):
    self.attribute1 = attribute

class Class2:
  def __init__(self, instanceName):
    setattr(self, instanceName, Class1(...))  # replace ... with whatever parameters you want
```

Comment: This, `setattr(self,instanceName,class1('attribute text'))` does seem to work, making instanceName a global instance of class1.

Comment: Though this worked in the example I gave, I got the same error message `NameError: name 'instance2' is not defined` when I incorporated this into the more complex program I was originally working on.